# how to add an ordered score table with names

Tags: python

```
import random
number_correct = 0

def scorer():
    global number_correct
    if attempt == answer:
        print("Correct.")
        number_correct = number_correct + 1
    else: 
        print('Incorrect. The correct answer is ' + str(answer))

name = input("Enter your name: ")

for i in range(10):
    num1 = random.randrange(1, 100)
    num2 = random.randrange(1, 100)
    operation = random.choice(["*", "-", "+", "%", "//"])
    print("What is the answer?", num1, operation, num2)
    attempt = int(input(" "))
    if operation == "+":
        answer = num1 + num2
        scorer()
    elif operation == "-":
        answer = num1 - num2
        scorer()
    elif operation == "*":
        answer = num1 * num2
        scorer()
    elif operation == "%":
        answer = num1 % num2
        scorer()
    elif operation == "//":
        answer = num1 // num2
        scorer()
print(name + ", you got " + str(number_correct) + " out of 10.")
```

I have made the quiz above and now want it to make a high-score table with the names and scores next to each other from highest to smallest.

I am trying to sort the scores first and this is what I have come up with:

```
scores = []
names = []
file = open("scores.txt","a")
addedline = number_correct
file.write('%d' % addedline) 
file.close()
file = open("scores.txt","r")
for eachline in file:
    scores.append(eachline)
    x = scores.sort()
    print(x)
file.close()
```

I don't think this works and am not sure how i will combine the names and scores at the end (making sure that the correct score is next to the correct name). Please help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the names and scores as a csv, then you could read the names with the scores and then sort with the score as a key.

```
with open("scores.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("%s, %s\n" % (name, number_correct))
with open("scores.txt", "r") as file:
    data = [line.split(", ") for line in file.read().split("\n")]

data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: -int(x[1]))

print("\n".join(["%s\t%s" % (i[0], i[1]) for i in data]))
```

Comment: how do i store them as csv?

Comment: it keeps coming up with invalid syntax. pls help

Comment: Oh my bad it looks like you're using Python 3, this is written in Python 2.7

Comment: I think the only difference was in Python 3 you have to call print as a function instead of a statement (with parentheses), so I changed that in my code above

Comment: And as far as storing as csv that's done in `file.write("%s, %s\n" % (name, number_correct))`, it just means that each line of the file will contain a record, and each record contains two values separated by a comma

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly your textfile looks but I would suggest using a dictionary (as long as you do not have the same score more than once).  Like this you could make the key your score and the value could be the name and the dictionary would automatically sort itself in order of the keys.